# Plotting graph from CSV

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib, plot

Im looking for a bit of help, Im really new to Python and dont know if it just making thngs harder for myslef or what. Im trying to plot a simple line graph from a csv file.
Ive tried a number of approaches but all return the error :
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

This is the code if seeming to get the best with

```
import csv`
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
matplotlib.dates as mdates
with open('D:/growth_rate.csv') as csvfile:
     readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

for row in readCSV:
    print (row)
a= (row)
np.shape(a)
x,y = np.loadtxt('D:/growth_rate.csv', delimiter = ',', unpack=True,
                         converters = {0: mdates.strpdate2num('%d/%m/%Y')})
```

Ive also tried the csv reader approach, but similar problem

```
a = zip(*csv.reader(open('D:/growth_rate.csv', 'rb')))
csv.writer(open('D:/growth_rate.csv', "wb")).writerows(a)

print a
```

I dont know if its a problem with the csv file, it originally was a xls file, with a company headers and other nonsense, so i put it into a csv and also tried a txt file.  Either that or im missing something really obvious,

Any help, greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post part of your CSV file or better a link to it or to excel file so we could download it and try to develop a working solution?

Comment: uploaded it to onedrive, let me know if the link works. Cheers https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=5D34F52D8051D718!3165&authkey=!AAYwslCeyK_R5Zs&ithint=file%2ccsv

Comment: there are no values in first two rows - is it OK? and how do you want to plot it as a line or as bars? Is it OK for you to use `pandas` module? - it's going to be much easier

Comment: yehm theres no data for the first two dates, yeh if it pandas works then thats great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do this in numpy / matplotlib without needing pandas. Note that `np.genfromtxt` can cope with blank lines fine (as opposed to `np.loadtxt` which will break. By default those values get filled with `NaN`s but you can change this with the `filling_values` option.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

date_decode_function = lambda b: mdates.strpdate2num('%d/%m/%Y')(b.decode())

dates, growth_rates = np.genfromtxt('growth_rate.csv',
                                    delimiter = ',',
                                    unpack=True,
                                    converters = {0: date_decode_function})


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(dates, growth_rates,'-',lw=2)
plt.xlabel("Date", fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel("Growth rate", fontsize=16)

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thats working. Brilliant. Is there any way i can have multiple graphs on the one output? Separate graphs but as if it was for the one print out. The csv file i uploaded is a smaller section of a bigger file

Comment: @anthonymccool You need to use the plt.subplot method. The exact invocation will depend on what you're trying to accomplish but the examples [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplot_demo.html) should help.

Comment: yeh something similar to that output, ill have a wee tinker and see what i come up with.
Thanks everyone, really helped me out there

Answer (score 0):

pandas approach:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt

fn = r'D:\temp\.data\growth_rate.csv'
#df = pd.read_csv(fn, parse_dates=[0], names=['date','val']).set_index('date')
df = pd.read_csv(fn, names=['date','val']).set_index('date')

# bar plot
df.plot(kind='bar')

# line plot
#df.plot()

plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]